# How to persist user_session for Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

How can one persist `user_session` using Rails Devise?

In other words, how a Rails application

1. Store a variable specific to `current_user` in `user_session`
2. Log out
3. Log in as the same user
4. Read that variable?

Comment: @MZaragoza, yes that's the default behaviour. I don't want it though. I want to be able to persist the view users can create – simply by using sessions.

Comment: @MZaragoza; No, I just want to persist some state of them.

Comment: Getting closer. But I want these settings to be specific to users. Think of two users using the same browser.